# Android - Showing progress dialog in a separate class which extends AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a class which is called `myAPI`, used for getting information from server db. This class has several classes used to get individual information, for example `getCourseInformation`, `login`, `register`, and many more.

It worked well until a point which I realized that I really need a `ProgressDialog`. An `Indeterminate ProgressDialog` to be exact.

Tried doing this :

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Context context;

    public myAPI(Context context)
    {
        this.context= context;
    }
    public myAPI()
    {

    }
```

To get the Context of the class from which the `myAPI` is called.

And below is how I use it in one of my class.

```
public class login extends AsyncTask<MyLogin, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
...
}
```

But it doesn't work. It says `Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Debugged it, and I could see that Context is there.. So it shouldn't be about that.. Any guide would be much MUCH appreciated!

Comment: What kind of `Context` are you passing on to `myAPI`?

Comment: It's a `Context` from the class which calls it, for example a `LoginClass` calls `login` method inside `myAPI` class

Comment: What I meant was, is this context an instance of an `Activity` or is it returned by `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()`

Comment: Oh it is an instance.. If by instance it means I pass the context from the Activity then yeah..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use context, try to use activity

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Problem is, it's in another class and it doesn't extend `Activity`.. Take it as a utility class I guess..?

Comment: progressDialog need to attached to an activity, so maybe pass the activity the same way as you pass the context

Comment: Ohh, hmm so I should make it like `progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);` after instantiating the activity up there? Or should I even extend the class to `Activity` and do `progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(myAPI.this);`?

Comment: Wait, attached to an `Activity`, so that means I must pass it anyways?